# How to Start/Stop Default Web Site and Application Pools in IIS7 programmatically

Tags: c#, iis-7, default

How to Start/Stop the Default Web Site and any Application Pool of the IIS7 programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something that you'd want to use WMI for. THe IIsWebServer class would probably be a good place to start looking, you can find documentation for that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525545%28VS.90%29.aspx). And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Start_Stop_IIS_Website.aspx)'s a codeproject article for stopping and starting sites in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use using System.DirectoryServices

http://terrapinstation.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/restart-iis-application-pool-from-aspnet-page/